# IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/user/.config/ibus/bus is not root?

Tags: hadoop, sudo, gedit

I am setting up paths for a Hadoop installation..
When sudo'ing into the hadoop environment config script I get:

```
 user@ubuntu $  sudo gedit hadoop-env.sh 

 (gedit:12017): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/user/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

Can anyone explain and help me fix this issue ?

Comment: Did you solve that issue ? If so can you post a response to yr own question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gksudo gedit hadoop-env.sh
```